I am trying to figure out what happened to my intel// arm command
I have been dabbling in different sorts of development and infrastructure wanting to potentially go back to school to get shift out of my current career path. I may not have the most in depth knowledge of everything happening with the ecosystem, but I usually can figure my way through most situations, but this latest has me perplexed…
In wanting to learn more about python and its usage, I set my infrastructure to be able to go between intel and rosetta, so I set up what I believe to be the correct command in all of my ~/.profiles, including sym links for commands. this worked fine until yesterday when I was able to to execute arch arm64 or arm and it would bring to that architecture, but trying go back to intel would yield a x86 architecture not recognized.
I checked all of my path variables and nothing had been modified, and as of right now, I dont know what to make of the conundrum.
this is my first time posting in here, so please be kind if I am lacking a crucial, albeit obvious, issue that I may have overlooked.
command : arch arm or arm64 yield to rosetta
command : intel or i386 or x86 yield to intel and visa versa.
currently able to switch from intel to arm, but get a infrastructure not recognized when trying to switch back.
